# Res.download() passing data instead of downloading the file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am attempting to pass a file generated by my NodeJS server from the server to the client as a downloadable file.

My users are filling in object data which is then stored in a DB, the function to create the file will read the objects to fill in data in the file that is generated. The file contains hexadecimal data(if this matters). Right now the user will select the objects he wants, which will group them into an array of objects, upon a button click on the front end, a POST request sends the array to the back-end to generate the file(this is working), after the file is generated, I check to make sure the file exists(it does), and then I attempt to send it back to the frontend with res.download('filepath/filename', 'downloadedname') (this does not cause a file to download, but does send a res, which what i believe is the expected content of the file in the res.data

Full code flow:
**AngularJS Controller:**

```
 function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, DashFactory, recipeBookService) {
  $scope.recipes = [];
  $scope.book = recipeBookService.getBook();
  for(i=0; i<$scope.book.length; i++){
    DashFactory.getRecipe($scope.book[i], function(data){
      $scope.recipes.push(data);
    });
  }
  $scope.empty = function(book) {
    $scope.book = recipeBookService.clearBook();
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };
  $scope.generate = function(recipes){
    DashFactory.generateFile(recipes)
  }

  $scope.delete = function(index){
    $scope.recipes.splice(index, 1);
  };
}
```

**AngularJS Factory:**

```
factory.generateFile = function(recipes, callback){
  console.log('factory recieved recipes', recipes);
  $http({
    url: '/createFile',
    method: 'POST',
    data: recipes
  }).then(function(res){
    console.log('success', res);
  },function(res){
    console.log('err', res);
  })
}
```

**Node Server(relevant section)**

```
const fs = require('fs');
createFile: function(req,res){
    console.log('server reciped recipes', req.body);
    if (createRecipeFile.writeRecipe(req.body)){
        fs.access('server/generatedFiles/RecipeTest.REL', fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
      console.log(`${'server/generatedFiles/RecipeTest.REL'} ${err ? 'is not readable' : 'is readable'}`);
        res.download('server/generatedFiles/RecipeTest.REL', "G4R12.REL")
        });

    } else {
        console.log('file creation failed');
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }

}
```

Expected result, is for the file server/generatedFiles/RecipeTest.REL to be downloaded as G4R12.REL, current results are a res that chrome logs as follows:

```
{data: "↵&2B����LX����… 
������������������������������{g]U", status: 
200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", …}
config:
data: Array(2)
0: {_id: "5be60e3d8bf74d716c2f5e1b", updatedAt: "2018-11-09T22:46:21.445Z", 
createdAt: "2018-11-09T22:46:21.445Z", name: "Gemini Twin 3 Batch 11-9 2:45", brewerName: "Gemini", …}
1: {_id: "5be60eb58bf74d716c2f5e1c", updatedAt: "2018-11-09T22:48:21.443Z", createdAt: "2018-11-09T22:48:21.443Z", name: "Gemini Twin 3 Batch 11-9 2:45", brewerName: "Gemini", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
headers: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8", Authorization: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoid…Dc5fQ.JPVQkZUaJ2651gyC1_L5jTiLQGAy3PxNjPbAGrPkm4s"}
jsonpCallbackParam: "callback"
method: "POST"
paramSerializer: ƒ (a)
transformRequest: [ƒ]
transformResponse: [ƒ]
url: "/createFile"
__proto__: Object
data: "↵&2B����LX�������=s�����}]=  �  �↵��}
]=����}�����������������������������������������������������������������������������{g]U"
headers: ƒ (d)
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
xhrStatus: "complete"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by piping the data to the frontend instead of res.download, and to tell angularjs to expect a blob in the http request res

**Node Server**

```
createFile: function(req,res){
    console.log('server reciped recipes', req.body[0], req.body[1]);
    console.log('from user', req.body[1]);
    createRecipeFile.writeRecipe(req.body[0], req.body[1])
    user = req.body[1];
        var file = 'server/generatedFiles/'+user+'.REL'
        fs.access(file, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log('err', err);
                } else{
            var count = 0
                console.log('reading stream');
                var fReadStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
                fReadStream.pipe(res);
            }
        })
},
```

**AngularJS Factory**

```
factory.generateFile = function(recipes, user, callback){
  console.log('factory recieved recipes', recipes, user);
  $http({
    url: '/createFile',
    method: 'POST',
    data: [recipes, user],
    responseType: 'blob'
  }).then(function(res){
    console.log('generate file res1', res, res.data);
    console.log('recieved data length', res.data.length);
    var file = res.data;
    FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'g4R12.REL')
  },function(res){
    console.log('generate file res2', res);
  })
}
```